# C# Set Form Parent after calling method from another class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, static, this

I've searched Google all day and can't find the correct answer to my issue, hoping someone here can help me.

So, in the "Main" form I have the method to show a form that needs to be centered directly above the parent form (frmMain). Normally I would call ShowDialog(this) to see the parent, but for some reason I have to set the loadNewsFeedItem to static in order to see the method from the flpNewsFeedHeader : Label derrived class (below). The OnClick event triggers the method loadNewsFeedItem().

When I call this to set the parent, I'm getting the message "Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer"

```
namespace NewsFeeds
{
public partial class FrmMain : Form
{
    public static void loadNewsFeedItem()
    {
        frmNewsFeedView frmFeedView = new frmNewsFeedView(FrmFuncs.selFeedID);
        frmFeedView.ShowDialog(this); // Error occurs on this line, when calling this via a static method
    }
}
}

public class flpNewsFeedHeader : Label
{
 private int FeedID = 0;

 public int theFeedID
 {
     get { return FeedID; }
     set { FeedID = value; }
 }

 protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
 {
     FrmFuncs.selFeedID = FeedID;
     Thread thrShowFeed = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FrmMain.loadNewsFeedItem));
     thrShowFeed.Start();
 }
}
```

Can someone please give me a corrected code example or a hint as to how to get the loadNewsFeedItem() to be visible without setting the accessor to static, or how to work around this in a static accessor?

Thanks in advance!

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: used ActiveForm for owner.

```
   public partial class FrmMain : Form
   {
      public static void loadNewsFeedItem(Form owner)
      {
         frmNewsFeedView frmFeedView = new frmNewsFeedView(FrmFuncs.selFeedID);
         frmFeedView.ShowDialog(owner);
      }
   }
}

public class flpNewsFeedHeader : Label
{
   private int FeedID = 0;

   public int theFeedID
   {
      get { return FeedID; }
      set { FeedID = value; }
   }

   protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
   {
      FrmFuncs.selFeedID = FeedID;
      // Shouldn't need a new thread.  Already on the GUI thread.
      FrmMain.loadNewsFeedItem (System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActiveForm);
   }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for saving me some sanity today. :)

Answer (score 1):

may be you mean this:

```
frmFeedView.Owner = System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActiveForm;
frmFeedView.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

In a static method, `this` is meaningless. One option is to skip the parameter

```
frmFeedView.ShowDialog();
```

The other option is to setup a static variable as shown below (but beware, it can have side effects if you try to open multiple instances of `FrmMain`)

```
public partial class FrmMain : Form
{
    private static FrmMain staticInstance;
    public FrmMain()
    {
       staticInstance = this;
       InitializeComponent();
       ...
    }

    public static void loadNewsFeedItem()
    {
        frmNewsFeedView frmFeedView = new frmNewsFeedView(FrmFuncs.selFeedID);
        frmFeedView.ShowDialog(staticInstance ); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Bala, to the best of my knowledge if I skip setting the this object then the form knows no parent, and without thist the form does not act as a child. Any advice?

Comment: @hutch32804 you are right about the parent/child relationship if the owner parameter is skipped. checkout my edited answer and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you Bala, both your editted solution and agent-j's response below resolved my issue! Giving agent-j the credit, only because I saw his solution first. Thanks again!